# Solana Token distribution (to multiple wallets) is not working

Tags: solana-program, token, solana-cli

Using the solana token distribution method to send SOL to multiple wallets. I keep getting an error saying that it expected a "tupple of size 2" in column 1, line 1 of the CSV file.

However I have formatted my CSV file just as the solana docs have prescribed.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide an example CSV file that's failing, the command that you're running, and the error output? Otherwise, it's going to be very difficult to figure out the issue.